# Is it good to consider elastic search a datastorage?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic search and i need to know it is even useful to store data?

because i was curious to try my hands on how elastic search works and i used postman>run elastic search then added some data in postman and then could able to do POST operation on the data

so i need to know without any database also how it is working?

Any explanation would be a great help

Comment: This would totally depend on what kind of data and app you use it for. Obviously enough, Elastic stores data, so for certain cases it is 'good enough'. But since it doesn't support ACID transactions, you would possibly run into concurrency issues for a lot of common use cases. There are a few other pitfalls that would make me very careful considering it as the main database for a project. It's basically meant to be a document retrieval system and should be used as such.

Comment: @thorstenmüller,

so ,If am using titan database in my application could you please explain me the flow if i need to do retrieving/updating operations?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Titan (or any graph database whatsoever). From Titan's website it seems there is some interface to ES at least for certain types of search features. But I have no idea how exactly this interacts with Titan's core features. The basic  storage backends seem to be Cassandra or HBase. These are all rather specialized tools, each of them with a rather steep learning curve. What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: @Shikhathakur See the links in my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it good to consider elastic search a datastorage?

It is even better to consider it a search engine.

But you are right, some people indeed use Elasticsearch as database.

See: [Jetslide uses ElasticSearch as Database](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/jetslide-uses-elasticsearch-as-database/)

> This post explains how one could use the search server ElasticSearch
>   as a database. I’m using ElasticSearch as my only data storage system,
>   because for Jetslide I want to avoid maintenance and development time
>   overhead, which would be required when using a separate system. Be it
>   NoSQL, object or pure SQL DBs.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch

> Elasticsearch supports real-time GET requests, which makes it suitable
>   as a NoSQL datastore, but it lacks distributed transactions.